# OS X disk utility error

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

I have an iMac running Snow Leopard and it shows low disk space. In the disk utility, if I try to verify my hard drive, it gives me an error and says to click "Repair Disk Permissions".

When I click that it says to reboot the system and insert the install disk, to run the disk utility from there.

I have the disk with me but the DVD drive on that computer isn't working, though I have 2 laptops with working drives on a LAN.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Offtopic, should be on superusers.

Comment: Ok , ill post it there ! :D

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to work around your broken DVD drive:

1. Use some other mac to copy the dvd-image to an memory stick large enough
2. Use some USB DVD drive
3. Remove the hard drive from the iMac and use a S-ATA-USB-converter to connect it to one of your laptops